# Mouse hover not working for Firefox browser using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Below are the firefox, gecko driver and selenium versions that I have used for automation scripts:
Firefox  browser: 52.0
Selenium: 3.0.1
Gecko driver: 0.11.1

Below is my code for mouse hover action:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver.getWebDriver());
WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='ciebar__menu-item ciebar__menu-item--has-dropdown medium-4 '])[1]/a"));
WebElement submenuxpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='ciebar__menu-item ciebar__menu-item--has-dropdown medium-4 '])[1]/ul/li[1]/a"));
action.moveToElement(mainMenu).moveToElement(submenuxpath).click().build().perform();
```

This code had worked properly for chrome and IE browser and facing issue only in Firefox. I have tried by upgrading Selenium and Gecko driver, but the that time the browser did not invoke. Below is the error message that is being displayed

> POST /session/dee48bec-9a8a-4ae7-92a3-f8fcbd218f5a/moveto did not match a known command Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d31c7c56c340d6f45a76976d43506cd6cc', time: '2014-06-03 10:52:47' System info: host: 'PC189896', ip: '10.243.169.86', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_141' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\313772\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.2bNvQAYH4V01, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, page load=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=52.0.1, platformVersion=6.1, moz:processID=11216, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}] Session ID: dee48bec-9a8a-4ae7-92a3-f8fcbd218f5a

Please help.

Comment: version: '2.42.2' looks like a Selenium version to me (which happens to be issued on 2014-06-03). Are you sure u actually use Selenium: 3.0.1? For Selenium version 2.42.2 you do not need gecko. But maybe there is a compatibility issue with FF 52.0.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `/{session id}/moveto` endpoint isn’t supported by geckodriver. There is a discussion about this [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/958) and a bug report was already filed against Selenium [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4564).